# Reset ImageView above ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have such layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/touchImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/robo"
        android:scaleType="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When i did long tap on **ImageView** it started to stick to finger. if it have quite far displacement through X i switched position of **ViewPager** like this :

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()+1,true);
```

**problem**:
During switching **ViewPager** coordinates of **IvmageView** is reset for a moment (to default) and then return to a position under finger (we are still doing long press on **ImageView**)

Comment: Do you want the image over layed to be swiped with the finger as well? why don't you insert it into one of the items?

Comment: no, image works only like controls to swipe ViewPager. it's completly separate

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, please elaborate

Comment: @KirillKulakov i recorded [video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1464534/files/2015-06-15_13-49-54.mp4) how it now works. pay attantion how image reset it position during switching ViewPager

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand what you trying to achieve from the video

Comment: @KirillKulakov  move image to left or to right side of the screen i tried to switch viewpager to that direction. like dropping app icons through screens(desktops) in android (from one to another)

Comment: The android aosp luncher is open-source, you can take a look at their code. But my guess is as soon as you pick the view from the pagerview, the view is removed from that hierarchy and moved to a frame that holds both the draged item and the view pager

Comment: @KirillKulakov yeah, i placed it to a different layouts and it worked ! where i can read about that more ? why it remove imageview from hierarchy ?

Comment: I have no a clue, it was just a lucky guess